# Как исправить No module named 'pyrogram.raw.all'?

Tags: telegram-bot, pyrogram

Подскажите, как исправить эту ошибку?

```
line 23, in <module>
    from ..all import objects
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrogram.raw.all'
```

Библиотека Pyrogram установлена.

```
pyrogram-1.4.16
```

23 строка файла tl_object.py"

```
from ..all import objects
```

`pip install pyrogram.raw.all` не устанавливается, пишет ошибку?

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyrogram.raw.all (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyrogram.raw.all
```

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.handlers import MessageHandler

api_id = cifry
api_hash = 'cifry'
app = Client('my_account', api_id, api_hash)

@app.on_message(filters.command(["start", "help"]))
def my_handler(client, message):
    print(message)

my_handler = MessageHandler(my_function)
app.add_handler(my_handler)

@app.on_message(filters.private)
async def hello(client, message):
    await message.reply_text(f"Hello {message.from_user.mention}")

async def my_function(client, message):
    await message.forward("me")

app.run()
```

```html
Нашел по этому пути pyrogram/setup.py такой код class Clean(Command): DIST = ["./build", "./dist", "./Pyrogram.egg-info"] API = [ "pyrogram/errors/exceptions", "pyrogram/raw/functions", "pyrogram/raw/types", "pyrogram/raw/base", "pyrogram/raw/all.py" ] Но тут нет такого файла "pyrogram/raw/all.py Похоже разработчики забыли наверное, вот я думаю, по этой причине этот файл tl_object.py Не может найти этот pyrogram/raw/all.py, его нет там.
```

Comment: pip uninstall pyrogram -> reload pc -> pip install pyrogram -> pip install pyrogram.raw.all

Comment: и вообще не кидайте код картинкой.

Comment: Удалил фото. tomato-magnet-regulato Ваш способ не помог, только pyrogram установился, а вот pip install pyrogram.raw.all выдал ошибку.

Comment: Нажмите -> править, и добавьте код вашей программы(бота) в формате кода, а не картинки

Comment: добавил код, но это всего лишь код теста с сайта, а он ругается на файл в библиотеке.

Comment: Решил собрать бота для телеграм, а тут сюрприз, на Aiograme проще, просто мне сказали, чтобы отлавливать события,кто добавил в группу контакты и добавить их в избранное, нужна эта библиотека.

Comment: from pyrogram.raw import .... или from pyogram.raw import <object>

Comment: https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135701/discussion-between-tomato-magnet-regulato-and-tikeo).

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Полный ктекст ошибки File "F:\1samoe_nuzhnoe\Py__Python\Telegram\PyCharm\pyrogram_tg_nov\pyrogram\raw\core\tl_object.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ..all import objects
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrogram.raw.all'

Comment: подключение модуля само по себе не правильное как мне кажется

Comment: Ну не я же, его подключал, это разработчики, я только папку распаковал в папку с ботов, а вот как это исправить?

Comment: В вопрос добавьте, а не в комментарий.